# Check if a list element exists in a string

Tags: python

I'd like to check if a string contains an element from a list:

```
l = ['S', 'R', 'D', 'W', 'V', 'Y', 'H', 'K', 'B', 'M']

s = 'YTG'
```

The first solution is:

```
for i in l:
    if i in s:
        print i
```

This seems inefficient though. I tried the following code but it gives me the last element of the list `'M'` instead of `'Y'`:

```
if any(i in s for i in l):
    print i
```

I was wondering what is the problem here?

Thanks!

Comment: `any()` just gives you a true or false value. `i` won't exist past the generator expression, so if you still have `i` it is a *different variable*.

Comment: Please post your desired output.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`any()` produces `True` or `False`, and the generator expression variables are *not available outside of the expression*:

```
>>> l = ['S', 'R', 'D', 'W', 'V', 'Y', 'H', 'K', 'B', 'M']
>>> s = 'YTG'
>>> any(i in s for i in l)
True
>>> i
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

Use a list comprehension to list all matching letters:

```
matching = [i for i in l if i in s]
if matching:
    print matching
```

That preserves the order in `l`; if the order in `matching` doesn't matter, you could just use set intersections. I'd make `l` a set here:

```
l = set(['S', 'R', 'D', 'W', 'V', 'Y', 'H', 'K', 'B', 'M'])  # Python 3 can use {...}
matching = l.intersection(s)
if matching:
    print matching
```

By making `l` the set, Python can iterate over the shorter `s` string.

Answer (score 1):

`any` will tell you if the condition is `True` or `False`, without giving more details.

To compute the actual common letters, just create a `set` and perform intersection:

```
l = ['S', 'R', 'D', 'W', 'V', 'Y', 'H', 'K', 'B', 'M']

s = set('YTG')
print(s.intersection(l))
```

that yields `{'Y'}`.

Answer (score 1):

One liner:

`set(list(s)).intersection(set(l))`

`{'Y'}`

As per @Martijn Pieters♦ comment simply:

`set(s).intersection(l)` will do the trick, as shown in @Jean-François Fabre's answer

Comment: You can drop the `list()` call and second `set()` call, they are only causing more work at 0 benefit.

Comment: Also, the OP is using Python 2; the output would be `set(['Y'])`.